# Upadate panel's child controls are not causing partial postback, the whole page gets reloaded with a flick

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

I have put several buttons and panels in my update panel. I also have a script manager on that page. now when I click on any of the buttons then the functionality is working fine but problem is that the complete page gets reloaded witha a flick, instead of updating the update panel only. 
I have set the "children as trigger" property of update panel "true".

please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem occurs if permissions of running Javascripts on your web browser are denied.